# JSpinner: Increase length of editor box

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I have a JSpinner that displays decimal values from 0.0 to 999.0.  It seems to work fine, except for when it displays a number in the editor box that is four-digits long, such as 123.4; it then cuts off part of the final digit because it is not long enough.

So my question is: Does anyone know how to increase the length of the editor window of a JSpinner?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the layout of the container into which you place the spinner? An an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) would be ideal.

Comment: I deleted my answer as when tested it was plain wrong.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get to the text field which in fact is a `JFormattedTextField` by

- First calling `getEditor()` on your JSpinner to get the spinner's editor
- cast the returned object to `JSpinner.DefaultEditor`
- Then call `getTextField()` on this.  Then you can set it's preferredSize if desired.

Edit: as noted by trashgod though, using a proper layout is paramount and being sure that the layouts you use are the best is probably the best way to solve this issue.

**Edit 2:**  The above is wrong as setting the textfield's preferred size does nothing. You can however set the preferred size of the editor itself, and that works.  e.g .,

```
import java.awt.Dimension;

import javax.swing.*;

public class SpinnerBigTextField {
   private static void createAndShowGui() {
      JSpinner spinner = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(0.0, 0.0, 999.0,
            0.5));

      JPanel panel = new JPanel();
      panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));
      panel.add(spinner);

      JComponent field = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) spinner.getEditor());
      Dimension prefSize = field.getPreferredSize();
      prefSize = new Dimension(200, prefSize.height);
      field.setPreferredSize(prefSize);

      JFrame frame = new JFrame("SpinnerBigTextField");
      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
      frame.getContentPane().add(panel);
      frame.pack();
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
      frame.setVisible(true);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            createAndShowGui();
         }
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: +1 [`BoxLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/BoxLayout.html), which respects preferred sizes, is particularly useful in this context.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels not agaist your person, just against rulles returns PreferredSize from Editor, in most cases I think that this's exactly job for programator not for LayoutManager, if I know that there are 4-5 numeric possitions ... or possible negative numeric sign, still is there moreover plus 5-8 pixels Horizontally and 2-5 Vertically for non-ugly look, how to solve that without exactly to JSpinner#setPreferredSize(), btw +1 for extract Component from compound JComponent

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels: Works perfectly.  Thanks!

Comment: I've posed a [variation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374659/jspinner-increase-length-of-editor-box/7376163#7376163) that relies on the component's preferred size.

Answer (score 14):

The first Hovercraft answers is not bad at all. You can not change the size directly, but you can do something like this:

```
JComponent editor = mySpinner.getEditor();
JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField();
tf.setColumns(4);
```

Where you can define the columns numbers showed by the editor. It will change the size of the spinner.

Comment: Thank you so much for the simple 3-line example! I've been looking everywhere for this :)

Answer (score 8):

As `FontMetrics` vary from one platform to the next, it's better to rely on the component's own calculation of preferred size. This example shows a spectrum of `JSpinner` sizes for various `min` and `max` values. Note in particular that [`FlowLayout`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/FlowLayout.html) "lets each component assume its natural (preferred) size."

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JSpinner;
import javax.swing.SpinnerNumberModel;

/** @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374659 */
public class SpinnerTest extends Box {

    private static final double STEP = 0.1d;
    private static final String FORMAT = "0.0000000000";

    public SpinnerTest(int axis) {
        super(axis);
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            int v = (int) Math.pow(10, i);
            this.add(genParamPanel((i + 1) + ":", -v, v));
        }
    }

    private JPanel genParamPanel(String name, double min, double max) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.TRAILING));
        JLabel label = new JLabel(name, JLabel.TRAILING);
        JSpinner js = new JSpinner(new SpinnerNumberModel(min, min, max, STEP));
        js.setEditor(new JSpinner.NumberEditor(js, FORMAT));
        panel.add(label);
        panel.add(js);
        return panel;
    }

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("SpinnerTest");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.add(this);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new SpinnerTest(BoxLayout.Y_AXIS).display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
JSpinner spn=new JSpinner();
spn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100,25));
```

Here,look This is the easy Answer.

Answer (score 2):

Changing the max value of a spinner will increase the size of the text box to accommodate the large number. If you do not wish to make the max value larger, i would recommend what @JorgeHortelano suggested...

> JComponent editor = mySpinner.getEditor();
>      JFormattedTextField tf = ((JSpinner.DefaultEditor) editor).getTextField();
>      tf.setColumns(4);