# JSpinner takes up entire width in JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing, width, joptionpane, jspinner

I'm trying to put a JSpinner in a JOptionPane as follows,

```
        SpinnerModel saModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(11, 1, 36, 1);
        JSpinner saSpinner = new JSpinner(saModel);
        Dimension d = saSpinner.getSize();
        d.width = 20;
        saSpinner.setSize(d);

        Object[] message = { "Choose the key number for sa.", saSpinner };

        JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(message,
                JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(frame, "Change Sa Key");
        dialog.setVisible(true);
```

This works, but the only issue is that the JSpinner fills the width of the Dialog regardless of the size I set. I've tried using setPreferredSize() as well. How do I fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not instead just put it in a JPanel?

```
  SpinnerModel saModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(11, 1, 36, 1);
  JSpinner saSpinner = new JSpinner(saModel);
  Dimension d = saSpinner.getSize();
  d.width = 20;
  saSpinner.setSize(d);

  // Object[] message = { "Choose the key number for sa.", saSpinner };

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(new JLabel("Choose the key number for sa:"));
  panel.add(saSpinner);

  JOptionPane optionPane = new JOptionPane(panel,
          JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE, JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
  JDialog dialog = optionPane.createDialog(frame, "Change Sa Key");
  dialog.setVisible(true);
```

Though myself, I don't know that I'd create a JDialog for this, but instead would simply display the `JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(...)` method:

```
  SpinnerModel saModel = new SpinnerNumberModel(11, 1, 36, 1);
  JSpinner saSpinner = new JSpinner(saModel);
  Dimension d = saSpinner.getSize();
  d.width = 20;
  saSpinner.setSize(d);

  JPanel panel = new JPanel();
  panel.add(new JLabel("Choose the key number for sa:"));
  panel.add(saSpinner);

  int selection = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(frame, panel, "Change Sa Key", 
          JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, JOptionPane.PLAIN_MESSAGE);
  if (selection == JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
     System.out.println("Sa Key is: " + saModel.getValue().toString());
  }
```

Comment: Yea, I actually switched to the showConfirmDialog method before you even posted your answer. But your JPanel method works great, so I'll accept your answer as soon as SO allows me to :)

Comment: `JPanel panel = new JPanel();`  Huh.  Very elegant - a left aligned `FlowLayout`.  Short & sweet.  I always get nervous at accepting the default layout of a component though, recalling Sun's decision to change the default of a frame from `FlowLayout` to `BorderLayout` around 1.5(?).

Comment: +1 More on `JSpinner` layout in this [Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7374659/230513).