# Fixing the size of a JSpinner

Tags: java, swing, size, spinner, jspinner

I have a  `JSpinner` object that fills the entire `JPanel` it is contained in. How do  I set a spinner to a single line and the maximum length of it is the panel width?

Comment: By using the appropriate layout manager.  See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html

Comment: U better add it to a `Panel` and sets its size `panel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 100));`

Comment: @Vitthal wrong, setXXSize a [no-no-never](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7229519/203657) ..

Comment: For [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374659).

Comment: 1) Don't include sigs. in questions, they are noise. 2) Use the correct case for J2SE classes.