# How to link JLabel and JSpinner for resizing

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I want to have a resizable App, and I am building a nested panels GUI. In one panel I need Spinners and Labels. I want the label to the left of the Spinner. What is the best way to achieve this when thinking about resize issues:

1.I could create a vertical BoxLayout panel, and add x sub-panels, where each sub-panel is
contains a label and a spinner:

```
JPanel ControlPanel = new JPanel();
ControlPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(ControlPanel, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
JPanel LabelledSpinner = new JPanel();
LabelledSpinner .setLayout(new BoxLayout(LabelledSpinner , BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
JLabel lab1 = new JLabel("Label1");
JSpinner spin1 = new JSpinner();
spin1.setModel(new SpinnerNumberModel(300, 10, 3000, 10));
LabelledSpinner .add(lab1);
LabelledSpinner .add(spin1);
ControlPanel.add(LabelledSpinner );
```

OR

2.I could create a GridBagLayout Panel with 2 columns and x rows. Then each row would have a label and then a spinner.

Which would best best?

Or does this "common" labeling issue have a simpler solution?

Comment: For me the 'GridBagLayout Panel with 2 columns and x rows' is better

Comment: Unrelated: please learn java naming conventions and stick to them.

Comment: Pains of nesting or self-inflicted :-) Or in other words: don't use nested panels at all, instead use a decent LayoutManager that is powerful enough to easily configure one panel that contains all. My personal favourite is MigLayout.

Comment: See also this related [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374659).

Answer (score 0):

1. Using the layout manager approach is definitely better.
2. There is a JDK Swing tutorial that talks about building form like layouts using the **SprintLayoutManager**
   http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/spring.html

Start with the standard layout managers. As you work with different layout managers, you will eventually come up with a combination that works best for your requirements.

Another alternative is using the GroupLayout which can help with adding slightly more complex components to your form UI. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/groupExample.html

Hope that helps.